# Relative change of several factors

Tags: linear-algebra

If we multiply a quantity by two or more coefficients, how do we calculate the percentage or relative proportions of the individual coefficients?
Example: x * 1.05 * 0.9high-1 * 0.8high-1 = y
How can I calculate the shares for 1.05, 0.9-high-1, 0.8-high-1, which affect the result.
It is not about the ratio of the coefficients, but about the effects of the individual factors on the result.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Some MathJax would help here, I cannot actually determine whether "high-1" is one variable or if it reads "high minus one"...

Comment: Having considered several possible interpretations of your cryptography I have concluded that your situation is the following:

$f\left(x\right)=a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot x$, how much do the factors $a,b,c$
  contribute to the value of $f\left(x\right)$? This would be answered by deriving $f\left(x\right)$
  with respect to $a,b$ and $c$.

Comment: With "high", do you mean raising a number to a power? For example 0.9high-1 $\rightarrow 0.9^{-1}$ ?

Comment: My simple answer: In a linear case like this, the "relative proportion of a coefficient" is the coefficient itself! If  you multiply something by $1.05$, to number becomes ... *drum roll* ... $1.05$ times larger!

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The term is high minus 1. It is a discrete function, not a continuous function. I want to weight the factors based on the output value.

Comment: To calculate with only one factor is easy. But there are multiple factors.